# How to get workspace name inside a python notebook in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying get the workspace name inside a python notebook. Is there any way we can do this?

Ex:
My workspace name is `databricks-test.`
I want to capture this in variable in python notebook

Comment: Did you find the solution? Most answers are outputting URL which does not contain the workspace Name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the workspace name (not Org ID which the other answer gives you) you can do it one of two main ways

```
spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.workspaceUrl")
```

which will give you the absolutely URL and you can then split on the first.
i.e

```
spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.workspaceUrl").split('.')[0]
```

You could also get it these two ways:

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext() \
.browserHostName().toString()
```

or

```
import json

json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook() \
  .getContext().toJson())['tags']['browserHostName']
```

Top tip if you're ever wondering what Spark Confs exist you can get most of them in a list like this:

```
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

Comment: If one doesn't have any tags indicating the environment, an alternative could be to have a config object like a dictionary in source code that maps the workspace IDs to names. This of course needs to be maintained manually or automatically in another process.

Comment: It gets workspace URL which may not contain workspace name.

Answer (score 0):

By using of below command , we can get the working workspace ID . But getting the workspace name ,I think difficult to find it .

```
spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterOwnerOrgId")
```

Comment: This should work

Answer (score 0):

We add the workspace name and the env name, among other attributes, to each cluster as custom tags. You will find them under Compute > CLUSTER_NAME > Configuration > Tags.

In your notebook, use the below command to get an array of dicts of all custom and automatically-added tags.

```
spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterAllTags")
```

If you named the workspace tag as `WorkspaceName`, you will have a dict in the form of `{"key":"WorkspaceName","value":"databricks-test"}`

Answer (score -1):

```
spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterName")
```

This command will return the cluster name :)